# TSQL table based function returning different tables

Tags: function, t-sql

I am trying to write a table based function so it returns a different results depending of the value.

I have:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tblfn_GetAnyDataSet_As_View]
(@DataType as varchar(50))
returns table as
return
select * from
(select * from table1 UNION select * from table2) DATA
where DATA.DataType=@DataType
```

and I want to upgrade it to something simular to:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tblfn_GetAnyDataSet_As_View]
(@DataType as varchar(50))
returns table as
return
Case @DataSet
when 'D1' then select * from table1
when 'D2' then select * from table2
else select 'Not Selected'
end
```

but case is not supported in table functions.  I need to keep this as a table function as I have other table functions which build on each other to create a final view which is used by SQL reporting services.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a Multi-Statement table-based function.
They work as standard table functions but are much like stored procedures.

Beware, though, you may suffer performance loss using multi statement functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IF @DataSet = 'D1' BEGIN SELECT ... END
ELSE BEGIN SELECT ... END
```

Answer (score 0):

I need this too...

The solution of Multi-Statement table-based function is good but not enough:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myProc (@ID Int)
   RETURNS @EmployeeList Table
     (  ID     Int
      , Name   nVarChar(50)
      , Salary Money
     )
 AS
   BEGIN
     IF @ID IS NULL
       BEGIN
         INSERT INTO @EmployeeList (ID, Name, Salary)
         SELECT ID, Name, Salary
         FROM Employee
       END
     ELSE
       BEGIN
         INSERT INTO @EmployeeList (ID, Name, Salary)
         SELECT ID, Name, Salary
         FROM Employee
         WHERE ID = @ID
       END
     RETURN
   END
 GO
```

One must    *d e f i n e*    a return table
so that a predefined field must be returned
and not any table like

```
if @tableNum=1
then select * from tableA --(tableA and tableB are completely differnt )
else 
select * from tableB
```